# why i can not get nodeType of node attributes as DOM standard says attribute is also a attribute node?

Tags: javascript, dom

I can get `nodeType` from nodes like `<a>` or `<div>` in Chrome devtools, but I can't get the `nodeType` of an attribute. I've tried like this:

```
document.getElementByTagName('a')[0].href.nodeType
```

The DOM Standard says attributes are also a type of node. Why can't get its `nodeType`?

Links : https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#attr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ...but I can't get the nodeType of an attribute. I've tried like this:
>
> ```
> document.getElementByTagName('a')[0].href.nodeType
> ```

When you access `.href` on an Element, you're not using the attribute node (not directly), you're using the *reflected property* for the attribute (which accesses the attribute node under the covers). That property is an accessor property that returns a string. Strings don't have a `nodeType` property. (You can find this in the HTML spec, starting at [the `a` element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-a-element) which tells you it's an [`HTMLAnchorElement`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#htmlanchorelement), which includes [`HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#htmlhyperlinkelementutils), which has [`href`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-hyperlink-href) which defines the behavior of the `href` accessor property.)

To access the attribute node directly, you'd use the [`attributes`](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-element-attributes) collection or [`getAttributeNode`](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-element-getattributenode):

```js
const example = document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
const node = example.attributes[0];
console.log(`node.nodeType = ${node.nodeType}`);
console.log(`node.nodeName = ${node.nodeName}`);
console.log(`node.nodeValue = ${node.nodeValue}`);
```

```html
<a href="http://example.com">example</a>
```

In a comment you've asked:

> But how do you know that?Does the Dom standard says that in any line?

Truthfully I've learned this stuff over a period of ~24 years and don't remember when I first learned that while attributes are part of the DOM, they aren't part of the node tree, they're held separately as the `attributes` `NamedNodeMap`. That information is in the DOM spec where it defines the [node tree](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#node-trees) (note that it doesn't mention attribute nodes), but...you'd have to be looking for it to catch that I think. :-) If you kick around the DOM and HTML specs long enough, though, you'll pick these things up.

Comment: Thank you!But how do you know that?Does the Dom standard says that in any line?

Comment: @JackieWillen - Yes, but...you'd have to be looking for it to spot it. :-) I've added some explanation of where you can find this info and more links above. Happy coding!